# UINavigationBar height and landscape mode

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uikit

If I use a UINavigationController to display my UINavigationBar, this bar is much slimmer in landscape mode than in portrait mode.

Everything fine so far, as I want this behavior, but I have one view which isn't handled by an UINavigationController and so I just dragged and dropped a UINavigationBar from Interface Builder into the view but this one has always the same size and I can't see a way to tell the UINavigationBar that it should resize.

Anyone knows how to achieve this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can resize the the navigation bar in the layoutSubviews method of your UIView, like so:

```
- (void)layoutSubviews {
    [super layoutSubviews];

    // Let navBar tell us what height it would prefer at the current orientation
    CGFloat navBarHeight = [navBar sizeThatFits:self.bounds.size].height;

    // Resize navBar
    navBar.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.bounds.size.width, navBarHeight);
}
```

Comment: That places the navbar at the bottom of the screen, shouldn't that be CGRectMake(0, 0, self.bounds.size.width, navBarHeight) ?

Comment: I wanted it at the bottom when I wrote that code, but typically yeah.

Comment: That does not work for me. I am doing everything in code (not in nib) and I could not get his work. Any suggestions?

Comment: @BorutTomazin The example is for a UIView subclass, I suspect you're using it in a UIViewController subclass instead, in which case you should use viewDidLayoutSubviews instead.